# SPRESENSE v1.2.0 にて、SPI接続のTFT画面に遅延が生じるようになりました

Tags: spresense

【対応】
以下の前バージョンに戻すと問題が発生しなくなります
SPRESENSE v1.1.3 リリース (2018/1/16)

今後のアップデートを受けるためにも、対策をご教授いただきたいです
よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 0):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

お問い合わせのTFT画面の遅延についてお答えいたします。

本件ですが、先日のリリース "v1.2.0" において、省電力化の対応を行った結果
SPIの非推奨API "setClockDivider()" に影響を与えてしまっておりました。
それにより、このAPIを使用しているライブラリにおいてSPIの転送遅延が
発生してしまっております。

こちらの症状ですが、次のリリースにおいて改善される見込みです。

また、非推奨APIを使用しないAdafruit社のTFTライブラリを使用した
Arduino sketchにつきましても、近日中に公開予定です。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Answer (score 0):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

TFT画面の遅延についてですが、昨日のリリース "v1.2.1" において、
非推奨API "setClockDivider()" での転送速度の改善を行いました。
是非こちらのバージョンに更新頂き、引き続きのご利用をお願いいたします。

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSEサポートチーム